# Rails - How to avoid inserting the html in method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in my project to show the title of books and a followed icon in the table. The method is:

```
def title_and_follow()
  "#{h.link_to object.title, h.show_book_path(object.uuid)}
   #{h.follow_icon(user, object)}".html_safe
end
```

It works fine and it shows something like "Harry Potter [followed_icon]" in my table. However, I wonder is there any way to avoid inserting HTML directly in the method? Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You mean not using string interpolation and then `.html_safe`?

You can use rails' `capture` and `concat` methods. Something like:

```
def title_and_follow
  capture do
    concat link_to(object.title, show_book_path(object.uuid))
    concat follow_icon(user, object)
  end
end
```

I think that should be a view helper method (right now it looks like it's somewhere else, not sure, it's not clear but that `h.` looks weird to me)